# Refresh scroll bars on winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a main-form in VB.Net in which I add a sub-form. The sub-form has the property TopLevel to false. I activated the scroll bars on the main-form (AutoScroll = true).

Now, at run-time, when I move the sub-form inside the main-form, the scroll bars don't appear immediatly. I should resize the main-form little bit in order to take the position of the sub-form into consideration.

Here is a video showing my problem : https://www.dropbox.com/s/eha23pc91ozrtni/2013-11-05%2006h02_41.mp4

I added the following code in the sub-form to refresh the main one in case of move but it's not working.

```
Private Sub Form2_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Me.Parent.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I tried also

```
Me.ParentForm.AdjustFormScrollbars(True)
```

but I'm having a compilation error, Overload resolution failed because no 'AdjustFormScrollbars' is accessible.

Does anyone know how to "refresh" the scroll bars on the main-form ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're expecting it to behave exactly like an MDI form.  Why not just set IsMdiContainer() on the main form and display the second form as a proper MdiChild?...

Comment: The parent form is already an MDI form. It's a Tabbed MDI control which will allow the user to execute different tasks in each tab. And among of the tasks opening some sub-forms inside the Tabbed MDI forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
Private Sub Form2_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Me.ParentForm.PerformLayout()
End Sub
```